# Getting Error AADB2C99067 when trying to request access token from Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have an Azure AD B2C tenant setup with an Angular app on the front-end using Authorization Code Flow with PKCE and a back-end api. Everything is working fine. I now have a need to allow the user to access certain pages on the front-end anonymously. I would prefer to still protect the apis these pages will call using the same access token.

I have followed the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to set up Client Credentials flow. I am able to get an access token successfully using Postman and use it to call my back-end apis fine. However, when I try to do the same from the Angular app, I get the following error:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADB2C99067: Public Client XXXXX-XXXXXX is not supported for Client Credentials Grant Flow\r\nCorrelation ID: 2b3346ef-1828-4900-b890-06cdb8e0bb52\r\nTimestamp: 2022-07-28 04:12:21Z\r\n"}

Below is the code snippet I am using in Angular to retrieve the access token.

```
const urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.set('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
urlencoded.set('client_id', '<clientid>');
urlencoded.set('client_secret', '<clientsecret>');
urlencoded.set('scope', '<scope>');
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
};
const url = 'https://<b2ctenant>.b2clogin.com/<b2ctenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<customPolicy>/oauth2/v2.0/token';
return this.httpClient.post(url, urlencoded, httpOptions);
```

Any ideas what could be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though azureadb2c supports client_credential flow.One may not use them with SPA apps.
***`This scenario is not supported by MSAL.js`***. Client credential flow/ grant type will not work in [***SPA***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration)s(Angular) because browsers cannot securely keep client secrets.
As  they may end up in the browser, visible to everyone and to attackers that load  them.

> **Note**:As the application's own credentials itself are being used, they must be kept safe - never publish that credential in your source
> code

If you are using it for web app , please make sure to select the platform as web or change the reply url type to be web.

```
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
        "url": "https......",
        "type": "Web"
    },
]
```

Please **refer** :

1. [Configure authentication in a sample Angular SPA by using Azure
   Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-angular-spa-app)
2. [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow on the Microsoft identity platform- Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Comment: Thanks. So, essentially we cannot use client credentials flow to protect our apis. Is there a reason why it works in Postman?